# Having trouble with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am trying to add select2 but it end up like this,

[image]

All i did is this,

```
$("#txtSearch").select2({
    placeholder: "Search"
});
```

and,

```
        <select id="txtSearch" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
```

not sure why it's showing my select , thought it will be hidden >?

Comment: Maybe there is a css selector that tragets :placeholder somehow? Please include a live example ( or at least the css)

Comment: You miss the CSS file. Are you including javascript and css code properly?

Comment: is there any css coming with select2 ?

Comment: Thanks guys you put me in right direction, i was using VS nugget package which didn't added css files, don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

You should call select2 plugin as follows in your js, unless you do so it will not load your multiple select.

```js
(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

Please find the js fiddle below, It will guide you for the implementation of multiple select box:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pramodga/2udu3c85/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue,

I downloaded select2 using nugget package in Visual Studio, which by default didn't added select2.css, which is why it was acting like this,

I went to this web and copied it to make it work,

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2

Comment: Any ideas about why I cant find select2 files when I installed it via NuGet?